# How to loop 'add' tag in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to count how many `Product` variations available in each `Market`. For now I'm only able to count `Product` variations for each `Distributor`. I'm thinking about using ['add' built-in template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) to sum `Product` variation in each `Distributor` to solve this problem, but don't know how to implement this in template `for` loop. Or is there any better solution? I'm open for suggestions.

My 5 related models in Django:

```
class Market(models.Model, RecordStatus):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Country(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Distributor(models.Model, RecordStatus):
    headquarter = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Product(models.Model, RecordStatus):
    video = models.URLField(verbose_name='Video URL', max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

class ProductStock(models.Model):
    distributor = models.ForeignKey(Distributor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My `views.py`:

```
def market_list_view(request):
    markets = Market.objects.all()

    context = {
        'market_list': markets,
    }
    return render(request, 'product_visualizers/market_list.html', context)
```

My current attempt on `market_list.html` template:

```
{% for market in market_list %}
   <h3>{{market.name}}</h3>

   <p>{% for country in market.country_set.all %}
      {% for distributor in country.distributor_set.all %}
          {{ distributor.productstock_set.all|length }}  # should I write |add besides |length to sum the numbers?
      {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

What should I code in the nested `for` inside the template?

Comment: Hint: Django's template language is limited _by design_ - anything else than presentation logic (and what you're trying to do is definitly domain logic, not presentation) should be performed outside the template (in your view, in a model method, etc). IOW, Pedram's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you for the hint. I didn't know about Django's template is limited by design before.

Comment: for some reasons they removed that part from the doc when adding support for 3rd part template engines, but you can still find it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/): "If you have a background in programming, or if you’re used to languages which mix programming code directly into HTML, you’ll want to bear in mind that the Django template system is not simply Python embedded into HTML. This is by design: the template system is meant to express presentation, not program logic."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
class Market(models.Model, RecordStatus):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_product_variations(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(productstock__distributor__country__market=self).count()
```

and for your template:

```
{% for market in market_list %}
   <h3>{{market.name}}</h3>
   <p>Product variations: {{ market.get_product_variations }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you Pedram for answering my question. This is exactly what I needed. If you don't mind, I would like to edit your answer to join 1 more related model. By adding `productstock` in front of `__distributor` at `get_product_variations` function.